To prove or disprove $MM^t=\alpha I_{m\times m}$,where $M$ is an $m\times n$ matrix of rank $m$ with $m<n$.
Let $M$ be an $m\times n$ matrix of rank $m$ with $m<n$. If for some non-zero real number $\alpha$, we have $x^tMM^t x=\alpha x^tx$, for all $x\in \Bbb R^m$ then prove or disprove $MM^t=\alpha I_{m\times m}$.

My attempt:Let $MM^t$=$[a_{ij}]_{m\times m}$.Then,
$e_i{^t}MM^te_i$=$a_{ii}$=$\alpha$.where $e_i$ is defined as $1$ at ith place and $0$ at all other places.Thus I am able to prove that all diagonal entries of $MM^t$ are $\alpha$.Now how to prove other entries equal to zero or it is just not possible at all.

Let call $M=(a_{ij})_{i \le m, j \le n}$, then the product on the LHS is given by
$$
[x^tMM^tx]_{i}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}^2\right) (x_i)^2+\sum_{j \ne i}^m \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} a_{jk}\right) x_ix_j
$$
Imposing that quantity equal to $\alpha x_i^2$ is imposing that $$\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}^2= [MM^t]_{ii}=\alpha$$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} a_{jk}=[MM^t]_{i \ne j}=0
$$
for each $j$, that is exactly what you want to prove

Excellent solution.Thank you so much.
